# How to find the bad start value guess when facing an initialization divergence in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

### I am using an open-source modelica library(ThermoSysPro) to build a simple Rankine cycle model, but it seems there is an issue about initialization.

[image]
[image]

### So I changed the debug setting as follows to check the log file:

[image]

### In the dslog.txt file, I could see there are a lot of errors in the same type:

[image]
[image]

### As the log file shows, all these errors are caused by iteration divergence and bad start values:

[image]

In order to see which iteration variable caused the divergence, I checked the iteration result of all the iteration variables, but they all seem in the right range. So I am not sure what I should do next to find the source of the divergence. The method in the Dymola help manual didn't work in practice.

### My question is how should I do to find the bad start values when facing the initialization divergence in Dymola?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the link of the library, the model I built, the log files generated.
[github link](https://github.com/alex19941215/ThermoSysPro)

[image]

Comment: Not a solution, just a related paper that you have already seen: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.12433.pdf

Comment: Hope that this solution could be adopted by Dymola as soon as possible, make it a lot easier to build models.

Comment: The philosophy of ThermoSysPro is just setting the equations in the component,  but there is no implicit initialization by setting start values or explicit initialization by using ````initial equation```` code. So, ThermoSysPro depends too much on Dymola's Solver, it uses the default values for most of the iteration variable, and that's why there is a serious divergence issue when using this library.  Currently, the best method is to ensure that when building some component, all variables are initialized with meaningful values according to the component's paramters